# How to install compass in mac?

Tags: terminal, sass, compass-sass

I would like to install compass through the terminal in mac. I installed sass. I now have Sass 3.3.0.alpha.175 (Bleeding Edge)

Then I tried to install compass with

```
sudo gem install compass
```

It gave me this warning

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:280: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:287: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
```

then stated the "1 gem installed"

When I run compass, it does not work, it gives me these lines:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19
    from /usr/bin/compass:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/compass:23
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Up to now I used codekit. But I would like to take advantage of sourcemaps and I believe the terminal is the only way to do it. I tried watching sass along with source maps and the result is beautiful (in that I could use chrome as an editor). But I'd like to add compass in there as well.

Is there a way to get this working?

I am using os version 10.8.3

Comment: Hmm did this a while ago and this worked smoothly... Have you tried tried a `sudo gem update --system` before? Oh and maybe you should not have installed sass on your own. I would uninstall everything and let the gem install do its thing. You could also try macports to install it. The port is not at the latest version though.

Comment: Hi @AlexandredeChampeaux thanks for your comment. I never used terminal before, when you say " I would uninstall everything and let the gem install do its thing" do you mean uninstall sass and compass (do you mean uninstall anything else?), and then how do I "let the gem install do its thing".

Comment: Yep uninstall compass and sass entirely. This might actually do the trick, compass does not seem to be compatible with sass 3.3.0 alpha (see [gem doc](http://rubygems.org/gems/compass) ). Then simply run sudo gem install compass, this will reinstall sass as well, properly. If that still don't work, you might try to uninstall ruby as well, there might be some issues with your install, or you might also have not completely uninstalled sass and compass.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexandredeChampeaux I uninstalled sass and compass and installed compass and it works great. I have another problem which did not have before, if I run this `sass --watch --compass sass:css` it works great, if I run this `sass --watch --sourcemap --compass sass:css` it does not "invalid option: --sourcemap". I cant remember how I did it before, can find the article I followed before. But I'm sure I will find a solution. btw put these comment in an answer so I can accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: If you know how to get the sourcemaps working, please let me know as I dont seem to know how to get it working

Comment: I don't know how to get sourcemaps working, maybe it's simply not compatible with sass prior to 3.3.0. By the way, you can simply use `compass watch` to watch for changes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Compass is not compatible with sass 3.3.0 alpha (see [gem doc](http://rubygems.org/gems/compass)). You should uninstall compass and sass, and the reinstall using `sudo gem install compass` which will install sass as well (with the right version).

EDIT:

Just tried to install compass with rvm today (26 Feb 2017) and stumbled upon another error: `Error compiling Compass LoadError on line [“179”] .. data.rb: Cannot load such file`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36927466/1411628) worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. Just in case other people see this. I research and the current version of compass does not work with source maps. As an alternative, I installed bourbon which offer mixins, and it works perfectly with source maps

Answer (score 9):

For what it's worth, if you're using RVM, then don't use sudo. Here's how I solved this problem (and I got here using Alexandre's answer):

1) `$ gem uninstall sass` 
(say yes to prompts alerting you about dependancies, you're about to reinstall anyway)

2) `$ gem install sass -v 3.2.10`

after that, compass is working great

Comment: Following these steps worked for me (the latest sass doesn't seem to be compatible with compass apparently). I'm now using compass 0.12.2 with sass 3.2.10.

Comment: After installing rvm, including in my ~/..bashrc I was able to :
rvm use 2.x.y
gem install compass

in my case rvm use 2.3.1

Answer (score 3):

in my solution: I have installed ruby. 
brew install ruby (I know already installed with mac) then 
sudo gem install compass