# Multiple versions of a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm currently using the gems [`scss-lint`](https://github.com/causes/scss-lint) and [`compass`](http://compass-style.org/); however `scss-lint` uses [`sass@3.3.0.rc.1`](https://github.com/causes/scss-lint/blob/master/scss-lint.gemspec#L24) and [this version isn't compatible with `compass`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17103686/398939).

I have `sass (3.3.0.rc.1, 3.2.12)` installed, so is there a way I can essentially separate the two `sass` versions so that I can use `compass` and `scss-lint` side by side?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the way I got around this was by installing the [latest alpha version of `compass`](http://rubygems.org/gems/compass/versions/1.0.0.alpha.15). This meant that I can now use the two gems together :)

Comment: While this solved your particular case; it does not specifically answer the question in the way you asked it and it is not applicable to the question as more general use case.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way the SASS dependency is set on both of those projects you cannot run both gems within the same gem set.  If you are using scss-lint to do command line linting though, you could just have each of these under separate gem sets and switch between the two as needed.  This does not preclude automation.