# Error compiling Compass LoadError on line ["179"] .. data.rb: Cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, rubygems

I've trawled every possible Ruby resource looking for a solution to this error but can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to get my sass compiler working for a Drupal build from a previous project. Using the following stack: Ruby 2.3.0, Sass 3.4.22, Compass & Compass Core 1.0.3, Bundler 1.11.2. I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling the gems but to no avail.

The error occurs when I run the `bundle exec compass watch` command, which results in the following output:

```
LoadError on line ["179"] of /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb: cannot load such file -- breakpoint
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb:179:in `require'
  /Users/somedude/Sites/devdesktop/taronga-dev/docroot/sites/tarongazoo/themes/custom/taronga/config.rb:9:in `get_binding'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in `eval'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in `parse_string'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:15:in `block in _parse'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `open'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `_parse'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:7:in `block in new_from_file'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/inheritance.rb:207:in `with_defaults'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:6:in `new_from_file'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:19:in `configuration_for'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:69:in `add_project_configuration'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:37:in `add_project_configuration'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:25:in `configure!'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:15:in `initialize'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:41:in `initialize'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `new'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `perform!'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:30:in `block in '
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:44:in `'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/compass:23:in `load'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/compass:23:in `'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  /Users/somedude/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'
```

Has anyone else encountered something similar when trying to get their SASS compiler to run? ANY help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved! It was such a simple oversight.

It turns out I just needed to call the missing gems via my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'compass'
gem 'sass'
gem 'sass-globbing'
gem 'breakpoint'
```

There were also a few version conflicts, but these were resolved by reinstalling gems by specific version, for example:

```
gem install breakpoint -v 2.5.0
```

Hopefully this points anyone else having similar issues in the right direction.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies should automatically be installed, but you could try manually installing the breakpoint gem that it can't find:

`gem install breakpoint`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Keith! Unfortunately the manual install of breakpoint doesn't seem to be resolving the issue. The error I'm getting is still the same. The breakpoint version I have installed is 2.7.0.